# How I can get the "pointer resolution" (or mouse DPI) on Windows?

Tags: windows, mouse

experts.

How I can query the mouse DPI (pointer resolution) on Windows?

I read the article [Pointer Ballistics for Windows XP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463319.aspx). It says "the typical pointer resolution is 400 mickey/inch". But how I can query the exact value used by various kinds of mice?

It would be great if you could also point me to documents related to this topic.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It's impossible to tell. The mouse DPI is simply the number of times the mouse reports a change in location when it's moved by one inch. On the other side of the mouse cord all you know is that you periodically get a change in location, and you simply move the pointer on the screen every time.

One thing you can do if this is critically important for some special application is to have the user move his/her mouse exactly one inch and count the changes in location. If you're doing this in some professional environment then it's probably worth your while to issue special equipment- give your users the same model of high-end mouse with a particular *known* DPI. I say high-end because for most mice the approximate DPI number will be ludicrously inaccurate.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Brian. However, I think Windows is able to retrieve this value when mapping mouse movement onto the screen, otherwise, a 400 dpi mouse must act very differently comparing with a 1000 dpi mouse. Right? And the XP ballistics document also uses it in calculation. I imagine that there might be a way to retrieve this value from the system.

Comment: High DPI mouses actually move the pointer faster so Windows lets the user adjust the mouse sensitivity in Control Panel. I think, you could go the same way.

Comment: As @rocket says, 400 dpi mice *do* behave very differently from 1000 dpi mice. People with high DPI mice have to turn down their mouse sensitivity in Windows and in games that use raw input so that the cursor doesn't fly all over the place.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about that. Thanks Brian and RocketR!

Comment: Is there any update for this answer after 10 years? @Rag