# Windows - read dpi setting of mouse in c++

Tags: c++, windows, mouse, dpi, mousemove

Is there a way to get the current mouse dpi setting in c++?

The problem is that sending a mouse move message to the system will result in a different cursor position depending on the dpi resolution of the mouse.

**edit:**

I found a solution where I don't need the dpi setting from the mouse. I get the mouse speed with SystemParametersInfo and calculate the move distance by:
moveDistance.x * 5.0 / mouseSpeed. The 5.0 / mouseSpeed is magic number which garantees the move distance will always be correct.

```
// get mouse speed
int mouseSpeed;
mouseSpeed = 0;
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETMOUSESPEED, 0, &mouseSpeed, 0);

// calculate distance to gaze position
POINT moveDistance;
moveDistance.x = m_lastEyeX - m_centerOfScreen.x;
moveDistance.y = m_lastEyeY - m_centerOfScreen.y;

// 5.0 / mouseSpeed -> magic numbers, this will halve the movedistance if mouseSpeed = 10, which is the default setting
// no need to get the dpi of the mouse, but all mouse acceleration has to be turned off
double xMove = moveDistance.x * 5.0 / static_cast<double>(mouseSpeed);
double yMove = moveDistance.y * 5.0 / static_cast<double>(mouseSpeed);

INPUT mouse;
memset(&mouse, 0, sizeof(INPUT));
mouse.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
// flag for the mouse hook to tell that it's a synthetic event.
mouse.mi.dwExtraInfo = 0x200;
mouse->mi.dx = static_cast<int>(xMove);
mouse->mi.dy = static_cast<int>(yMove);
mouse->mi.dwFlags = mouse->mi.dwFlags | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;
SendInput(1, &mouse, sizeof(mouse));
```

I hope this helps someone :)

Comment: Have you tried using Windows Management Instrumentation? Try this one here: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation)

Comment: Thank you very much bash.d I will read through. :)

Answer (score 1):

The question about retrieving mouse dpi was asked previously here: [How I can get the "pointer resolution" (or mouse DPI) on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182199/how-i-can-get-the-pointer-resolution-or-mouse-dpi-on-windows) - the answer there seems to suggest that it isn't possible, which makes sense as it would likely be specific to the mouse hardware/driver in use.

As far as setting a cursor position goes though - if you use a function like [`SetCursorPos()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648394(v=vs.85).aspx), and are working with [`WM_MOUSEMOVE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645616(v=vs.85).aspx) messages the coordinates you are working with are absolute, not relative, and shouldn't depend on the dpi of the mouse at all.

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you for your answer I also read the previously asked question, which was asked 2011, so I hoped there could be a solution available now. :) I cannot use SetCursorPos(), I have to use SendInput with relative mouse move.

Comment: Can you give more information on what you're trying to do with this? Even using relative mouse movements with `SendInput` I can't see that this would be affected by the dpi of the mouse hardware..

Comment: In a 3rd person shooter I want to send a relative mouse move to the current gaze position (gaze position = the position on screen where your looking at. This information comes from my eyetracker). This mouse move is affected by the dpi settings of the mouse. I can get the current speed of the mouse as defined in the windows mouse settings with SystemParametersInfo, but I can't figure out how to get the dpi settings of the mouse...

Comment: Can you calibrate the program beforehand to get the mouse dpi.. or sample the rate of mouse movement during normal movement and use this to get _some_ idea of the dpi - or at least, of how the dpi affects the movement?

Comment: Thats my fallback solution. :) Because its not that accurate and feels a bit like a hack. I will give it a try. If I find a solution or a way how to achieve it, I will post it here. Thank you very much, Michael.

Answer (score 0):

```
INPUT mouse;
memset(&mouse, 0, sizeof(INPUT));
mouse.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
// flag for the mouse hook to tell that it's a synthetic event.
mouse.mi.dwExtraInfo = 0x200;
mouse->mi.dx = static_cast<int>(xMove);
mouse->mi.dy = static_cast<int>(yMove);
mouse->mi.dwFlags = mouse->mi.dwFlags | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;
SendInput(1, &mouse, sizeof(mouse));
```

Instead of this you can use this:

```
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, xMove , yMove , NULL, NULL);
```